# Single word lucene indexing limit?

Tags: lucene

I've a Lucene based application and obviously a problem. 
When the number of indexed document is low no problems appear. When then number of documents increase, seems that no single word are indexing. What we obtain is that searching with single word (single term) is an empty set.
The version of Lucene is 3.1 on 64 bit machine and the index is 10GB.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/fileformats.html#Limitations), Lucene should be able to handle 274 billion distinct terms.  I don't believe it is possible that you have reached that limitation in a 10GB index.

Without more information, it is difficult to help further.  However, being that you only see problems with large numbers of documents, I suspect you are running into exceptional conditions of some form, causing the system to fail to read or respond correctly.  File Handle leaks or Memory Overflow perhaps, to take a stab in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My supposition is that something wrong happen during the optimization of the index. One thing that I didn't report is that not for every single term this happens. Just for some terms. And if we combine the term A with another term, lets say B documents are found. Furthermore, if we analyze a subset of documents, with the same versione of SW, the problem does not happen. Is a very strange problem.

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear to me.  All I know is that you run a query, and don't get the results you expect.  What evidence causes you to suspect a failure in optimization?  Can you demonstrate the issue your talking about more concretely?  What queries are used to generate documents "for term A" and "when combining A with B"?  Code and examples are helpful.

Comment: Lets suppose to index the following documents:

D1="Your explanation isn't clear to me. All I know is that you run a query, and don't get the results you expect. What evidence causes you to suspect a failure in optimization?"

D2="Can you demonstrate the issue your talking about more concretely?"

When search with the term "evidence" the document D1 is not retrieved. When search with the term "evidence causes" the document D1 is retrieved. As I wrote previously, this not happen for all the terms.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with analysis.  Stopword and Synonym filters seem likely culprits, but it's hard to make any useful guess at it, without any information about your implementation or examples (since you say it doesn't happen for all terms, it may or may not really happen for the random example you gave as an illustration).

Comment: Solved...it was a problem of timeout. We execute the search in a separate thread, obviously we wait for a specific amount of time for the response, otherwise the result is not valid. In specific cases not the lucene search but the creation of highlights is slow due to the dimension of some documents. Thanks for your time spent to help me.